# Programmatically added elevation is not showing on Lollipop or Marshmallow devices

Tags: android, view, fragment, android-linearlayout, android-elevation

I am trying to add elevation to a LinearLayout (in a fragment). On my device with Android Nougat everything is fine but on Marshmellow or Lollipop there are no shadows at all. What could be the problem?

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.main_ll_newproducts);
    ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(50,50,50));

        LinearLayout llProduct = new LinearLayout(getContext());
        llProduct.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.product_selection_background);
        llProduct.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        llProduct.setPadding(20,0,0,0);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            llProduct.setElevation(8);
        }
        llProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });

        //Layoutparams
        LayoutParams layParam = (LayoutParams) ll.getLayoutParams();
        layParam.setMargins(10,10,10,30);
        layParam.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        layParam.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        // /Layoutparams

        llProduct.setLayoutParams(layParam);
```

after that I add a few more views like Textviews and one ImageView and then I add this LinearLayout to its parent.

```
ll.addView(llProduct);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the LayoutParams was the problem. I replaced it by this:

```
//Layoutparams
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        layParam.setMargins(20,10,20,30);
        layParam.width = FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        layParam.height = FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        llProduct.setLayoutParams(layParam);
        // /Layoutparams
```